# How to open up a new Excel Workbook in MS Access VBA that's of the newer format?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access and Excel 2010.

In MS Access VBA, I create/open new workbooks like so:

```
Set objXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set xlWBk = objXl.Workbooks.Add
```

And despite having Excel 2010, for whatever reason this workbook only goes up to 65535 rows, I assume because for some reason it defaults to .xls when making a new book or something.

It's only when I save as xlsx/close/reopen it do I get the full 1-million plus rows:

```
xlWBk.SaveAs someFilePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook 'xlsx format AFAIK
xlWBk.Close
Set xlWBk = objXl.Workbooks.Open(someFilePath)
```

Is there a way to default the creation of a new Excel workbook to be in .xlsx format with the full number of rows without needing to save/close/reopen it?

Edit: In my case, changing the default save method in Excel's options doesn't seem to be sticking for whatever reason. New workbooks always want to open up in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: What is your default save format set to in Excel's options?

Comment: @Rory Oh man, 97-2003... is that all it is?!

Comment: Unfortunately not, it didn't solve the problem even after changing the default save option to .xlsx :(

Comment: Does it default to .xls both when creating and opening the file?

Comment: I think it may have to do with this "compatibility mode" when I open Excel? (edit: Looks like it went back to 97-2003 default save format even though I had just picked .xlsx earlier)

Comment: Have you tried using the Microsoft Excel Object Library instead of the way you are doing it? Does it create also a xls file?

Comment: Yes, it also creates an xls file / opens in compatibility mode

Comment: No weird compatibility settings have been checked either when right-clicking / checking the compatibility tab for Excel, all users, etc.

Comment: Maybe you can try to change `objXl.DefaultSaveFormat` before creating the workbook?

Comment: @VincentG That worked! Thank you! If you'd like to make that an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [default format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.defaultsaveformat) before creating the workbook:

```
Set objXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXl.DefaultSaveFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' or xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Set xlWBk = objXl.Workbooks.Add
```